# ImportError: cannot import name 'Ingredient' from 'inventory.models' (C:\Users\mcarl\OneDrive\Desktop\VirtualEnvs\djangodelights\inventory\models.py)

Tags: python, django, shell, django-models

So I am at a point in my project where I need to create instances of my models inside of the python shell.

The problem is when I go to import my Ingredient model (which I've checked probably a hundred times now to find out if it was correct), I get this message - ImportError: cannot import name 'Ingredient' from 'inventory.models' (C:\Users\mcarl\OneDrive\Desktop\VirtualEnvs\djangodelights\inventory\models.py)

The file structure is correct and everything..

How are they saying there is no Ingredient when there is a model called Ingredient inside the file..?

Any idea how to fix.?

Thanks

My models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    available_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    price_per_unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_place=2)


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class RecipeRequirement(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_required = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    quantity_purchased = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    total_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_place=2)
```

File structure, fixing typos, clearing python cache..

Comment: Can you show your import statements? Also are you returning names or anything from the classes?

Comment: use forward slashes in the path `/` or double back slashes \\.